# RegEx js: how to correctly reuse patterns using capture groups?

Tags: javascript, regex, capture-group

```
let string="James 18 Jenny 38 ";
let regEx=/(\w+\s\d+\s)\1/;
let result=string.match(regEx);

console.log(result)
```

I was trying to understand how can I reuse patterns with capture groups but the console returns null:

Can somebody explain me please why with this approach it doesn't work?
If I duplicate as below it returns in the way I imagined, thus I probably miss something about the syntax, but I don't understand what.

```
let string="James 18 Jenny 38 ";
let regEx=/(\w+\s\d+\s)(\w+\s\d+\s)/;
let result=string.match(regEx);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: the backreference `\1` matches the same what is captured in group 1, which is not the case here.

Comment: the pattern matches and captures first `James 18 ` and then `\1` tells that [`James 18 ` has to be found again](https://regex101.com/r/mgic61/1/) which of cause does not match with the remaining `Jenny 38 `.

Comment: A backreference within a pattern is helpful e.g. in case of targeting patterns which might come with [varying characters within an otherwise stable pattern](https://regex101.com/r/IIlQye/1/) like differently used quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`\1` doesn't reuse the *pattern*, it looks for another instance of what *matched* the pattern. In your example, it's looking for another `James 18` and not finding it.

You could use a `{2}` quantifier to look for two matches of a pattern next to each other, but then the capture group would either include just one of them or both of them (depending on where and how you applied the quantifier). For instance, here it has both:

```js
let string = "James 18 Jenny 38 ";
let regEx = /((?:\w+\s\d+\s){2})/;
let result = string.match(regEx);

console.log(result[1]);
```

Or use just one instance of the pattern in a loop:

```js
let string = "James 18 Jenny 38 ";
let regEx = /(\w+\s\d+\s)/g;
let result;

while ((result = regEx.exec(string)) !== null) {
    console.log(result[1]);
}
```